# Residuals Diagnosis and its Covariance - Timeseries

Tags: machine-learning, time-series, forecasting, residuals

I need some clarification about Residual Diagnosis and its covariance.
I read this [article](https://www.otexts.org/fpp/2/6).

> A residual in forecasting is the difference between an observed value
> and its forecast based on other observations: ei=yi−y^iei=yi−y^i. For
> time series forecasting, a residual is based on one-step forecasts;
> that is y^ty^t is the forecast of ytyt based on observations
> y1,…,yt−1.

My first question is which period should I use to calculate the residual.
My assumption is to use all the data (Learning Data and Test Data) to calculate it. Is that correct? According to the example in the article.

The second question is about its covariance. Which other variable should I choose to calculate his covariance? The sales of each day? The forecast for each day?
I have really no idea of the right data.

Comment: I this case covariance refers to self-covariance, that is the covariance between the residuals and themselves, I advise this [book](https://books.google.pt/books/about/Introductory_Time_Series_with_R.html?id=QFiZGQmvRUQC&redir_esc=y) to get started on these topics.

Comment: But the correlation of a variable with it-self is 1. So the residuals will always be correlated. 
There to have an idea of how good my forecast is, i need it to be uncorrelated. 
I read more about this since I posted this, maybe i have to see the correlation of residuals and my predictors/features one by one.

Comment: The correlation is only 1 for a lag difference of 0, that is between t=0 and t=0 or t=4 and t=4. The correlation for a lag difference different than 0 is always a number between 0 and 1, for example the correlation between t=0 and t= 4 can be 0.5